# Do some websites force gzip encoding?

Tags: java, network-programming, gzip, okhttp, packet

I'm currently working with OKHTTP and I've ran into a situation where accepting gzip encoding in my header, would cause text to come back malformatted (i know, its just gzipped).

My solution is to just pull that out of any headers that get passed into my program, replacing gzip with: Accept-Encoding: identity

My question is, will I likely run into any websites that won't like this header? Will this work universally? or is there websites that force gzip encoding? Normally simply doing a quick fix would be fine, but this is being put into a tool that should work with any website the user needs it for.

Comment: You know, I would consider a different career if it wasn't working so good! Stack overflow exists to allow people to reach out to the community with questions. You have dodged my question multiple times to talk trash

Comment: Someone with as much reputation as you should be here to help. Not to be toxic towards people with less than your 20 years of experience. I have done very well for myself with programming. I don't care if you know how to simulate the universe in Java, nothing matters if you don't apply it in a business. Why don't you take a step off your high throne and think about actually helping people instead of telling me to get a new career. That doesn't belong on an educational site like StackOverflow.

Comment: I am here to help. I asked a comment to clarify your question because it didn't make much sense that you would deploy broken code and assume that it works because other programmers are more careful than you are. Then you got an attitude, because apparently you think you're entitled to get help even when being aggressive. So yeah, take a good look at yourself and think about your actions.

Comment: I'm not deploying broken code. Have you considered that I don't work for someone else? I'm writing code and testing something, and I don't need gzip getting in the way. My library didn't decompress it. I don't want to make my own decompress method when I'm already testing something else.

Comment: I never assumed you were working for someone else, on the contrary. I just suggested you fixed your code, which you apparently understood as "write your own decompression code". I meant that you're most likely not using the http library correctly, because they're quite capable of decompressing the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the standard (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.4) all servers SHOULD either obey identity or send the response without encoding, which is the same thing. In other words you are not **likely** to run into problems. On the other hand SHOULD means that there may be circumstances where this does not apply, so it may happen. Plus not all servers follow the standard.

Comment: Thank you! I will be working on implementing gzip in the future. For now I am testing basic functionality and not worry too much about gzip.

Answer (score 1):

If you omit the `Accept-Encoding` header altogether, OkHttp will automatically request a gzipped response, and then decompress it before it is returned to you.

Comment: Just to clarify. Would it be a good idea to remove user inputted accept-encoding headers? Because I'm loading packets from user defined templates